# Can't add to arrayList in method

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

For some reason I cannot access my arrayList that I created in my main method of my program from the rest of my methods in my main class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //creating array list for vehicles
    ArrayList<motorVehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<motorVehicle>();
    getAndCheckMainSelection();
```

At the end of my collection of input for my object and I go to create and add values it gives a error in netbeans that says variable can't be found highlighting vehicleList..

```
vehicleList.add(new car(wheels, engineSize, valueOfPS, date, serialNumber, doors, color));
```

Comment: Read up on variable _scope_.

Comment: are you sure all those variables in new car() are present?  Does it work if you do car newcar = New car(wheels, engineSize, valueOfPS, date, serialNumber, doors, color);    vehicleList.add(newcar);

Comment: Variables in one method are not visible to other methods. Make them fields, or pass them as parameters.

Comment: This is basic Java. You didn't pay attention on your lecture.

Comment: I did but I think I decomposed my problem alittle to much. Instead of having differnent methods for selection to add remove vehicles and what subclass they are of I bundled it up in my main method and my create methods (car, truck,etc...) are return that type to be added to the vehicle list in the main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vehicleList` is local variable, you can access local variables only in method they are declared, if you want to use `vehicleList` in an another method you should declare it as instance variable, class variable or pass it as parameter. You can read more about them in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: You're correct but your answer is missing the keyword. *Scope*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your arrayList to be visible to all methods. In this case. Use it like this:

```
public class Myclass {

private static ArrayList<motorVehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<motorVehicle>(); //has to be static to be accessed in static methods

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Do your stuff

getAndCheckMainSelection();

}
```

As you can see, I declared vehicleList as private. This means that it can be used anywhere but only in this class!

Comment: how you can access non static object in static method?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to add your data(entries) to a variable which exists only in the `void` main class. Make the `vehicleList` variable exist in the class `Scope` for it to be accessible to all methods (Static aside)